# Mac bash copy all files of one dir to another dir

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I have a folder which contains two dirs: `build` and `copy-build`.

I need that through bash copy the files that are inside `copy-build` in `build`.

If these files already exist it must overwrite them.

I tried with:

```
 cp -r ./SourceFolder ./DestFolder
```

But the `SourceFolder` folder is copied into `DestFolder`, instead I need the `SourceFolder` files to be copied into `DestFolder`.

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: `man` is your best friend on shell scripting. Run `man cp` on your terminal.

Comment: In the end it seems that I have solved it.

Comment: I generally prefer to use `rsync` rather than `cp -R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-R` option instead of `-r`, and explicitly include a `/` in the name of the source directory.

```
cp -R ./SourceFolder/ ./DestFolder
```

From the description of the `-R` option:

> If the source_file
> ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than
> the directory itself.

---

From the compatibility section of `man cp`:

> Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation
> supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it
> does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.

Comment: I just tried this, it seems to work: cp -r ./copy-build/. ./build
Can you tell me what changes?

Comment: So it's advisable to use -R instead of -r, right?
So is the final point after the slash useless?
./SourceFolder/.

Comment: Yes, the extra slash is what makes each file from the source be copied into the destination, rather than the source directory itself.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no subdirectories in `SourceDir`, you should try

```
cp ./SourceFolder/* ./DestFolder
```

See [the manual](https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html) for more info.

Comment: In the end it seems that I solved it, I did something like this: cp -R ./copy-build/. ./Build